# Excel formula to return a value if two values are true and one of two other things are true

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing

I'm trying to write a formula in Excel where if value in B is “Eligible/Previously Eligible” and value in C is more than 365 days before today and value in D contains either 10 or 20, then return the value in A. I’ve been searching around and have written this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,SMALL(IF((COUNTIFS($B:$B,"Eligible/Previously Eligible",$C:$C,"<"&TODAY()-365,$D:$D,{"*10*","*40*"})),ROW($A:$D)-MIN(ROW($A:$D))+1),ROW(A1)),COLUMN(A1)),"")
```

And have activated with the CTRL+Shift+Enter combo, but it just pulls in everything from A regardless of what is in B, C, or D:

[image: image of what is being returned]

@Solar Mike and @Scott Craner, thanks! This has gotten me closer but not quite there. I have a formula now that works to return the ID numbers that meet the criteria:
 `=IF(AND(B2="Eligible/Previously Eligible",D2<TODAY()-365,D2<>"",OR(SUM(COUNTIF(C2,{"*10*","*20*"})))),A2,"")`

But I still can't get it to give me a list without white space. So, I can get what's in the "ID Numbers with Problems" column, but what do I need to write to get it to show the way I've done it manually in the "What I want" column?

[image of what](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2SN0.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add a helper column:

```
=and(find("*elig",B2,1)>=1,now()-c2>=365,D2/10<=2)
```

Drag down to test each row. Then a results table based on those that give true.

Or use sumproduct() with column A to give the IDs.

Comment: I think you are missing a `(`  And you probably want SEARCH instead of FIND.  As FIND is case sensitive